# Django - how to get length and count commands in template? (query-set in template)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have these modules: Sales, Gender and Type in Django.

Table 1:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="-")
    sgender = models.ForeignKey(MainGender, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stype = models.ForeignKey(MainTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sdate = models.TextField(default="-")   

    +------+-----+------+------+
    | name |gende| type | date |
    +------+-----+------+------+
    | A    | 1   | 1    | 2019 |
    +------+-----+------+------+
    | B    | 2   | 1    | 2018 |
    +------+-----+------+------+
    | A    | 1   | 3    | 2019 |
    +------+-----+------+------+
    | C    | 2   | 3    | 2017 |
    +------+-----+------+------+
    | A    | 1   | 2    | 2019 |
    +------+-----+------+------+
```

Table 2 (key)

```
class MainGender(models.Model):
    mid = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="-")
    mgender = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="-")

+----+--------+
| id | gender |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Male   |
+----+--------+
| 2  | Female |
+----+--------+
| 3  | -      |
+----+--------+
```

Table 3 (key)

```
class MainTypes(models.Model):
    tid = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="-")
    ttype = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="-")

+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
| 1  | U1   |
+----+------+
| 2  | X2   |
+----+------+
| 3  | B1   |
+----+------+
| 4  | H3   |
+----+------+
```

Then, I want to count all the things in the main table and show them in the template as below

```
+---------------+---+
| Total records | 5 |
+---------------+---+
| Male          | 3 |
+---------------+---+
| Female        | 2 |
+---------------+---+
| Type U1       | 2 |
+---------------+---+
| Type X2       | 1 |
+---------------+---+
| Type B1       | 2 |
+---------------+---+
| Type H3       | 0 |
+---------------+---+
```

I can only get total records in template by code below

**in views.py**

```
def Sale_p(request):
    saless = Sale.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'sale.html', {'sales':saless})
```

I tried these codes in the template (sale.html)

```
{{ sales|length }} (gives you total records in Table 1, in this example 5)

{{ sales.gender|length }} (gives nothing)

{{ sales.type|length }} (gives nothing) 

{{ sales.gender_set|length }} (gives nothing)

{{ sales.type_set|length }} (gives nothing)

{{ sales.gender(1)|length }} (gives nothing)

{{ sales(gender='1')|length }} (gives nothing)

{{ sales.gender.count() }} (gives nothing)
```

They did not work in template. I want to see in records how many times we had 'male' or 'female' or types and so on...

**in template, sale.html**

```
+---------------+--------------------+
| Total records | {{ sales|length }} |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Male          | ?                  |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Female        | ?                  |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Type U1       | ?                  |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Type X2       | ?                  |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Type B1       | ?                  |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Type H3       | ?                  |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

What should be the codes to get the results for others?
Or should I use different ways in views.py?

Comment: first of all, don't use reversed fields name like `type, id` it's not correct. And while in you sale model there is type field and it's ForeignKey Category?

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen thank you. I changed them.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the link below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: I read this page but I didn't know how I could save variables and then show all these fields in template. If we use for loop, we need to compare and store the result in somewhere and then at the end show them. In this simple example how we can use this method to get these results? Also, I'm not sure if I used the right thing in views.py, if there is something better to give us the answers directly from views.py.